# Nil pointer evaluation in template...why? Is there a better strategy?

Tags: go, go-templates

I am attempting to wrap html/template so I am guaranteed to have certain data in my templates (session data for example) in addition to the data I want to render.  However, my current approach is...flawed.  Here's a simplified example below:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"
import "html/template"

func main() {
    // Passing nil directly to Execute doesn't render anything for missing struct fields
    fmt.Print("Directly rendering nil\n")
    tmpl, err := template.New("master").Parse("Foo is: {{.Data.Foo}}")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
        return
    }

    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
        return
    }

    // Wrapping templates works as long as I supply data...
    fmt.Print("\nRendering Foo\n")
    render(struct {
        Foo string
    }{
        "foo",
    })

    // ...but this breaks.
    fmt.Print("\nRendering nil\n")
    render(nil)
}

func render(data interface{}) {
    allData := struct {
        Session string
        Data    interface{}
    }{
        "sessionData",
        data,
    }

    // Hardcoded template for the example - this could be any arbitrary template
    tmpl, err := template.New("master").Parse("Foo is: {{.Data.Foo}}")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
        return
    }

    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, allData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
        return
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Directly rendering nil
Foo is: 
Rendering Foo
Foo is: foo
Rendering nil
Foo is: template: master:1:15: executing "master" at <.Data.Foo>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.Foo
```

So I'm not quite sure what's going on in the first place - why is it that html/template is capable of handling being passed `nil`, but can't figure out what to do with a nil pointer?

Secondly, is there a better way of approaching this problem?

Comment: That might be a bug, try with Go1.6 if you haven't, otherwise try to file an [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/new).

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to always make Data a map or struct, either by making the type a map or struct, or by not using a nil with `interface{}`:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"
import "text/template"

func main() {
    tmpl, err := template.New("master").Parse("{{if .Data.Foo}}Foo is: {{.Data.Foo}}{{else}}Foo is empty{{end}}")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
        return
    }

    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("")

    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, struct {
        Session string
        Data    map[string]string
    }{
        "sessionData",
        nil,
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("")

    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, struct {
        Session string
        Data    interface{}
    }{
        "sessionData",
        map[string]string{},
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("")
}
```

Play: http://play.golang.org/p/9GkAp6ysvD

As for why it works like this, it's a bit complicated, you have to look at the code: https://golang.org/src/text/template/exec.go?s=4647:4717#L521

When execute is called with nil, `reflect.ValueOf(nil)` returns an invalid Value, so evalField returns the zero value, and you end up with an empty string.

However, when execute is called with a valid struct, that first reflect.ValueOf returns a valid value. The `.Data` command calls evalField on the whole struct you passed to Execute, and evalField calls FieldByIndex/FieldByName to get the "Data" field. This doesn't return an invalid Value.

Next, when `.Foo` is evaluated, if Data is an interface or a pointer, the [indirect](https://golang.org/src/text/template/exec.go?s=4647:4717#L831) function follows it to the end, and if it finds that it's nil, it fails with this error.

When Data is a map, the indirect function doesn't do anything, and it doesn't fail.

This might be a bug in the text/template package.